# Rails - Text is larger in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I have an app deployed in Heroku and everything is working fine except for the fonts, it seems to be rendered bigger compared when viewed locally.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wicked\_pdf font size too large in production](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694543/wicked-pdf-font-size-too-large-in-production)

Comment: There could be multiple reasons of that. Can you see any missing fonts or css in browser console? Can you please add more info, so that we can help you debug this.

Comment: @PardeepDhingra, It use the default font on production, I use web fonts instead to fix the issue.