# wicked_pdf I want to solve the problem that display size is different between heroku and local environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, heroku, wicked-pdf

wicked_pdf I want to solve the problem that display size is different between heroku and local environment.

We are displaying pdf of html using wicked_pdf on rails site.
In that case, the local display size and the size of pdf are very different, so please tell me how to match.

## controller

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.pdf do
    render     pdf: 'file_name',
            layout: 'pdf.html.erb',
            template: 'question/show.pdf.erb',
            encoding: 'UTF-8',
            page_size: 'A5',
            margin:  {   top:               0,
                         bottom:            0,
                         left:              0,
                         right:             0 }
  end
end
```

## html

```
<!--pdf.html.erb-->
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag wicked_pdf_asset_base64('pdf') -%>
  </head>
  <body onload='number_pages'>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

## local Image

[image]

## heroku Image

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the version of wkhtmltopdf on heroku vs your local box?

Answer (score 0):

try to set the font size in css
[wicked_pdf font size too large in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694543/wicked-pdf-font-size-too-large-in-production)

or you could take a look of this, see if that helps
https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/670